# PHP read txt file with specific format

Tags: php

I need some help with a txt file reader.
There is a file based on following format:

```
{
    id    0001
    1   00000   1   10
    2   00000   1   0
    3   00000   1   0
    4   00000   1   0
}
```

This textfile contains various of these blocks.
I wanna read id and all four variables per line.
That i have an Array at the end with:

```
[
"0001_1" => ["var1"=>"1","var2"=>"00000","var3"=>"1","var4"=>"10"],
"0001_2" => ["var1"=>"2","var2"=>"00000","var3"=>"1","var4"=>"0"],
"0001_3" => ["var1"=>"3","var2"=>"00000","var3"=>"1","var4"=>"0"],
"0001_4" => ["var1"=>"4","var2"=>"00000","var3"=>"1","var4"=>"0"]
]
```

Finally i want to show those data in a Table.
So if you have some better idea, how to transform this text file blocks into table, let me know :D

My first try was to read whole txt as string and then read all betwenn "{" and "}" to save this and remove it from string an continue reading my separators from string.

Then i was thinking about 2D Array and maybe someone at Stackoverflow knows a better way.

```
    public function readFile(){
        $source = file_get_contents(storage_path().'\app\public\file.txt',"r");
        $found = $this->get_string_between($source,"{","}");
        $source = str_replace($found,"",$source);
    }

    public function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return '';
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }
```

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code attempting to parse the text into the desired array.

Comment: Looks like maybe tab-separated data, barring the weird brackets at either end - if you can discard/ignore those then it might not be too hard to process. Are you having trouble reading the data, or getting it into the desired output format, or something else? You sort of described what you want, but didn't actually explain what the problem is, specifically

Comment: I want to find a smart solution to transform this text into a table.

Comment: Define "smart". That's pretty subjective. What are your criteria? What do you feel is wrong with the code you've shown? What we think is smart might not be what you think is smart. Be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses preg_splits.  To split the file into lines, and to split each line.  You could swap $in for a file_get_contents() call.

```
<?php
$in =<<<IN
{
    id    0001
    1   00000   1   10
    2   00000   1   0
    3   00000   1   0
    4   00000   1   0
}
IN;

$lines = preg_split('/\R/', $in);
$lines = array_map('trim', $lines);
$lines = array_map(function($v) { return preg_split('/\s+/', $v); }, $lines);
$lines = array_filter($lines, function($v) { return count($v) == 4; });

echo '<table>', "\n";
foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo '<tr><td>', join('</td><td>', $line), '</td></tr>', "\n";
}
echo '</table>', "\n";
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>00000</td><td>1</td><td>10</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>00000</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>00000</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>00000</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

If the cell order is wrong, you could just swap the echo/implode line for a printf with the correct placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

something like this will do the job for all matching lines with this structure:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("./2.txt", "r");
if (!$handle) {
    echo "Failed to read file";
    exit(1);
}
$arrData = array();

$counter = 1;
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    preg_match('/^\s+([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)\s+$/', $line, $matches); 
    if(count($matches) == 5) {
        $key = '0001_' . $counter;
        $counter++;
        $arrData[$key] = array(
            'var1' => $matches[1],
            'var2' => $matches[2],
            'var3' => $matches[3],
            'var4' => $matches[4]
        ); 
    }
}
fclose($handle);

echo json_encode($arrData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "\n";
```